# Capture image of a node without background in SceneKit

Tags: swift, core-graphics, scenekit, arkit, core-image

I have a ARSceneView that has few nodes. I would like to capture an image of these nodes without the camera background. The snapshot() method gives an image of nodes with camera background.

I thought on setting the scene background to clear color as follows:

```
sceneView.scene.background.contents = UIColor.clear
```

In order to make this work, I store the background contents in a new variable as follows:

```
let storedBG = sceneView.scene.background.contents
```

Then, I take the snapshot: `sceneView.snapshot`. Finally, set the background to its original value:

```
sceneView.scene.background.contents = storedBG
```

As a result of this process, I get an image of my nodes without background.

The above strategy works, but it doesn't look very safe and there seems to be better ways of accomplishing the same result. For instance, I thought of creating a new image by taking the difference of two images.

In order this to work, I would use `sceneView.snapshot()` which will contain nodes and background and `sceneView.session.currentFrame.capturedImage` that will only include the raw camera frame without nodes. Then I would use CoreImage, CoreGraphics or other library to calculate the difference of those two images to get the nodes without background. It seems to me this approach might work.

However, I'm not experienced with CoreImage, CoreGraphics or any other relevant library to make this happen. Can someone please help?